# OpenGL never reverts to default FrameBuffer

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So I'm trying to change the texture using FBOs, When I run it, The whole game gets drawn in the new FBO that I created then deleted, Here's the function

```
public void ChangeTextureBuffer(int width, int height, ByteBuffer newBuffer) {
    int frameID = glGenFramebuffers();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameID);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    Texture texture = new Texture(width, height, newBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.ID);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(-1, -1);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(1, -1);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(1, 1);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(-1, 1);
    glEnd();

    texture.Delete();
    glDeleteFramebuffers(frameID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

And here's what I'm getting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fanSD.png

It's getting drawn where I want it to be with the size that I want, I just don't want everything to be drawn there.

Here's how its supposed to look, Everything getting drawn in its place, I just want to change the text on the bottom left side to show the FPS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc2JT.png

Also when I delete a texture or framebuffer, OpenGL isn't reusing the id, I don't know if that's a feature or a bug.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting any errors? Because `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING` is not a valid parameter for `glBindFramebuffer` ([docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindFramebuffer.xhtml)) and should result in a GL_INVALID_ENUM.

Comment: @BDL It wasnt giving any errors, i changed it and its still not working

Comment: How did you check for errors? And you only replaced it in the second instance but not in the first. I now wonder even more that your code even does anything. Which OpenGL implementation are you using? Because `glDeleteFramebuffers` has two parameters, not just one.

Comment: By error do you mean the program will throw an error or is it something else, Before it was changed the code was compiling and running and it is still after i changed it, but the bug remained

Comment: import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*; Edit i just realised im using 30 in the Texture class and 11 in the spriterenderer class, Does that matter ?

Comment: In OpenGL you have to check for error yourself, for example, by checking the return value of `glGetError()`. Methods do not throw exceptions when you parse wrong values.

Comment: You need to check for errors using [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml).

Comment: @BDL im getting 1280

Comment: I just realized that i have the same GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING on the glBindFrameBuffer too i removed it and now it says 0 which is no errors i assume, still the problem remains

Comment: @Rabbid76 Width and height are the width and height of the new buffer, ID is the old texture that i want to change, new buffer is the ByteBuffer of the new texture

Comment: @Rabbid76 but newBuffer isn't same size as ID

Comment: And that has nothing to do with the question, Why is it drawing everything to the new FrameBuffer even tho I'm binding back to the default

Comment: @Rabbid76 as i said newBuffer isnt the same size as ID

Comment: The viewport needs to have the size of the framebuffer (the size of ID).

Comment: Okey, I made it the way you told me, bug remained.

Comment: The code in the question looks fine. There is a bug in your code elsewhere. `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);` binds the default framebuffer. After this instruction everything is drawn to the screen.

Comment: When I don't update the texture it doesn't happen

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the code in the question is correct.

Comment: Where do you enable and disable texturing (`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`)? Is it always enabled?

Comment: it is always enabled, is that a problem ?, I enable it at the start of the gameloop

Comment: @HamzaNasab No that is not problem. It was just a question about the context. I'm just seeking and thinking about your issue.

Comment: I just got it to work by using glViewport again to make it the size of the screen, althought its working it's drawing over the old texture, is there a way to clear the texture before drawing on it.